# In React Router, how do i remove / change the param in history.push that i have sent before?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, react-router

I am using react-router-dom version 4.3.1, and I am passing param to another route, all things are working fine but now I have to change / remove that param, how do I do that ?

I have tried this

```
this.props.location.state.deleted = false
```

```
//admin profile page
history.push('/home/admins', { state: { deleted: true } });

//all admins page
componentDidMount(){
  const checkDelete = this.props.location.state.deleted // true
}
```

Basically I am deleting admin from his/her profile page and then navigate to all admin page and in this page I want to show success message of deletion of admin.

so I am working with **true** like,

```
componentDidMount(){
  const checkDelete = this.props.location.state.deleted // true
  if(checkDelete){
   this.setState({
    messageAlert:true
   })
  }
}
```

and alert will close automatically, but checkDelete is always true, how do I make it remove or making it false.

Comment: If I get this right, you are redirecting to the same url but with a different state?

Comment: initially there in no state in all admin page and after deletion i am making a state of deleted:true , you are getting it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack of `history` object is maintained by router and every time it will get the `state: { deleted: true }`. One possible hack could be to update the history stack by pushing the same route address but setting the `state: { deleted: false }`.

we can do this in `componentDidMount` like this:

```
  const checkDelete = this.props.location.state.deleted // true
  if(checkDelete){
   this.setState({
    messageAlert:true
   }, () => { 
      history.replace('/home/admins', {state: { deleted : false }}) // false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 const state = { ...history.location.state };
 delete state.deleted;
 history.replace({ ...history.location, state });
```

On hiding message alert success use the above code snippet.